# Covariance and Contravariance Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I read about in C#, `covariance and contravariance` enable implicit reference conversion for array types, delegate types, and generic type arguments.

I'm wondering can I use the covariance and contravariance for Anonymous Types (which are class types derive directly from object) and how would that works ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I use  covariance and contravariance of generic interfaces and delegates with anonymous types?

Yes. Anonymous types are *reference types*; variance only works with reference types.

> How?

Interface covariance:

```
var sequenceOfAnonymous = from c in customers select new {c.Name, c.Age};
var sequenceOfObject = (IEnumerable<object>)sequenceOfAnonymous;
```

Array covariance:

```
var arrayOfAnonymous = sequenceOfAnonymous.ToArray();
var arrayOfObject = (object[]) arrayOfAnonymous;
```

To demonstrate delegate covariance you need to use a generic type inference trick:

```
static Func<R> MakeFunc(Func<R> f) { return f; }
...
var funcOfAnonymous = MakeFunc( ()=>new { X = 123 } );
var funcOfObject = (Func<object>)funcOfAnonymous;
```

Interface contravariance needs a slightly different trick: casting by example:

```
interface IFrobber<in T> { void Frob(T t); }
class Frobber<T> : IFrobber<T> 
{ 
    public void Frob(T t) { Console.WriteLine(t); }
}
...
static IFrobber<T> FrobByExample<T>(IFrobber<T> frobber, T example) 
{ return frobber; }
...
var frobberOfObject = new Frobber<object>();
var frobberOfAnonymous = FrobByExample(frobberOfObject, new { X = 0 });
```

And similarly for delegate contravariance:

```
static Action<A> ActionByExample<A>(Action<A> action, A example) 
{ return action; }
...
var actionOfObject = (Action<object>) x => { Console.WriteLine(x); }
var actionOfAnonymous = ActionByExample(actionOfObject, new { X = 0 } );
```

Make sense?